# Can Django contribute_to_class method be used with abstract models?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Is there a way to use contribute_to_class method with abstract models, such that it would be executed separately for each child?

I have the following models:

```
class BaseHistoryModel(Model):
    change = JSONField(blank=True, verbose_name=_('Change'))
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class HistoryHelper:
    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, *_args):
        self.create_history_model(cls)

    def create_history_model(self, cls):
        attrs = {'__module__': cls.__module__}
        history_model = type(
            '{}{}'.format(sender.__name__, 'History'),
            (BaseHistoryModel, ), attrs
        )
        history_model.target = models.ForeignKey(cls)
        return history_model


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    history = HistoryHelper()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I need it to create a separate history model for every child of `BaseModel`, but when I run `makemigrations` all I get is one change which creates history model for the abstract `BaseModel`. Is there a way to somehow get it to create one for every child?